Keen-slider: Change animation duration and easing type for swiping
In the Keen Slider documentation, defaultAnimation is supposed to set the animation for moveToIdx, next, and prev functions. However, it only affects next and prev, not moveToIdx. I can change the animation duration for button clicks but not for swiping. Here's the reproduction of the issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-wuvuih?file=app.vue.
If we take a look at the unminified keen-slider source code and go to line 436 -https://codepen.io/simulant144/pen/WNqJvqz, there was a duration set to 500ms by default. If we change it to n.options.duration and then go to the line 825 and change this duration to let's say 5000ms it starts to work. Is there a built-in way to set the animation duration and easing type to something like cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1 particularly for swiping without going deep into the source code and changing it manually?
const current = ref(0);
const [container, slider] = useKeenSlider({
  slides: {
    perView: 1,
    spacing: 15,
  },
  initial: current.value,
  slideChanged: (s) => {
    current.value = s.track.details.rel;
  },
  defaultAnimation: {
    duration: 1300, // works only for navigation buttons and when clicking on gallery thumbnails, but not when swiping
  },
});

Looking forward for a possible solution.

According to docs defaultAnimation.duration should affect moveToIdx as well. I suggest you open an issue on keen-slider's repo and wait for a proper fix, since the current behavior is clearly not the intended one.

@tao Yeah it should, but it doesn't. I already opened the issue yesterday, but I wanted to also post it here, since I'm not sure if I'll ever get an answer there. Looks like the dev doesn't respond too often. https://github.com/modbender/nuxt-keen-slider/issues/1

@tao So everyone who helps on StackOverflow is getting paid for the answers now? Interesting. By the way, I'm not asking to fork the plugin, I'm asking if someone here knows what's the issue because I might be missing something in the docs and if someone had a similar issue, they might help me by telling the solution to it. If you don't know the solution, please let others do it. I'm here to get help

@tao if you point to where I say 'fork this public plugin and fix this bug/add this feature for me' I take my words back and apologize. You just made it up. Don't make a mountain out of a molehill

Oh, I must have misunderstood. I thought you're asking for a bugfix from someone other than the package maintainer/author. Apologies.

No, you're not missing anything in the docs. They clearly state defaultAnimation "Sets the default animation of the functions moveToIdx, next and prev."

Please read on-topic. Specifically, point 4.

@tao I've seen dozens of non-removed questions from people here on StackOverFlow with a bunch of upvotes regarding popular libraries like keen-slider, splidejs, swiperjs, embla etc. that hundreds of big companies like Tinder and Rakuten use daily in their projects, but I never thought that specifically my questions 'aren't generally a good fit here or need additional information' as it is said in the point 4. That probably makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the reference.
